# Put Javascript inside an URL column in Yii GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'm trying to put these buttons inside my GridView:

```
$extraButtons = array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn', 
                updateButtonLabel => 'Atualizar',
                deleteButtonLabel => 'Excluir',
                viewButtonLabel => 'Visualizar',
                deleteConfirmation => 'Deseja realmente excluir este ítem?', 
                buttons => array(
                    'btnCVs' => array(
                        'label'=> 'See resumes',
                        'url'=> 'javascript:viewResumes($data->id_professional)', //here is the line
                        'imageUrl' => '/gammarh/assets/dad4ddbc/gridview/cvs.gif',
                        'visible' => 'true',
                    )),
                template => '{btnCVs} {view} {update} {delete}', 
                viewButtonOptions => array("target" => "_blank"),           
        );
```

I`d like to put a function inside each generated line. When I do that I receive the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yiiroot/framework/base/CComponent.php(616)
```

I`ve already tried to escape the : character, use urlencode.. and nothing.

Somebody knows how to resolve it?

Thanks,

Armando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
'url'=> '"javascript:viewResumes(\"".$data->id_professional."\");"', //here is the line
```

(you can leave out the escaped quotes if you are only passing an id.)

The other option would be to pass a unique id to each button and attach a click event on page load.

Comment: Great. It works. So this string still will be processed with an eval().